# Передача файла по сети через сокеты

Tags: сокет, c++

Как можно передать файл с расширением .ехе размером, допустим, 30мб через сокет? Какие функции использовать? Какой алгоритм?

//--------------------------------------------------------

Столкнулся с такой вот проблемой: не могу отправить файл кусками, то есть буфер у меня 1024, а файл, допустим, 17*1024. **Не получается считывать по очереди 1024 байта с файла**.
ReadFile & fread читают полностью файл, не обращая внимание на размер записываемого буфера. Пробовал так же игратся с позицией в потоке и fgets? но так же ничего не вышло. Кто знает каким способом можно высылать частями файл?

//---------------------------------------------------------

Уже разобрался , всем спасибо за помощь)
Конечний код передачи файла:

```
FILE *in = fopen("SocketServer.exe","rb");
while(!feof(in)) {
b=fread(bufer,1,sizeof(bufer),in);
size=ftell(in);
printf("bytes read: %d, part:%d, pos: %ld \n",b,i,size);
if(b!=0)
send(current,bufer,b,0);
i++;
}
```

Ну и прием файла:

```
while (1)
 {
  int nbytes = recv( soc, buf, sizeof(buf), 0 );
  if ( nbytes == 0)
  {
    cout<<"Disconnected."<<endl;
    return;
  }
  if (nbytes < 0)
  {
   cout<<"Error: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
   return ;
  }
    WriteFile(F2,buf,nbytes,&j,NULL);
    cout<<nbytes<<","<<i<<endl;
    i++; 
 }
```

Comment: Вы работаете с сокетом как с обыкновенным файлом. Самый простой способ это просто открыть файл exe на чтение, и записать его в сокет. Ну и как-то маячить типа "начало данных" "данные" "конец данных"

Comment: Нигде не нашел нормального примера передачи файла через сокеты. Покажите пожалуйста кусок кода, где реализируется открытие файла и передача его через сокет.

Comment: В одном окне `nc -l 2000 > outfile`, в другом -- `nc localhost 2000 <infile` -- вот вам и передача файла через tcp-сокет сплошным потоком. (nc -- это утилита netcat) Расписывать это на c++ лениво.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли, я хочу написать свою программу, а не использовать уже готовую.

Comment: так-с, на чем вы вообще остановились при работе с сокетами? И еще, какая ось? Какие-то библиотеки используете?

Comment: Я остановился на том, как мне файл просто предать с клиента на сервер(или наоборот, неважно. Видел много исходников где просто передают сокету через send & recv содержание символьного буфера(при этом не указывая как они загружают содержание файла в буфер), но я не представляю как можно передать таким образом бинарный или же исполняемый файл... Работаю на Windows 7, Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010, Winsock2, vcl.

Comment: Да какая разница, что передавать: тестовый файл, музыкальный или исполняемый? Все это представляет собой просто последовательность байтов. Вот их считываете в символьный буфер и потом отправляете в сокет. При чтении последовательность обратная.

Comment: @mikillskegg Не забывайте, что в dos/windows есть "текстовые файлы", где по ctrl-z наступает конец файла. @1101_debian про ось -- это WSAStartup? (остальные функции можно и общие использовать)

Comment: При записи как в сокет, так и в файл у Вас **ошибочка**. Писать надо **не** sizeof(buf), а ***количество прочитанных*** байт. Иначе (если размер файла не кратен размеру буфера) в конце файла будет грязь.

--

Для начального обучения алгоритм сойдет, а на практике - как приемник  узнает, что весь файл успешно передан ? 

Если передатчик "умрет" досрочно, приемник получит 0 при recv() и подумает, что это конец файла.

Comment: @Rocketdeath, поправили код и ошиблись (наверняка не тестировали).

Не sizeof(b), а b и не sizeof(nbytes), а nbytes.

Comment: Совершенно верно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@1110_debian ну не сообразил я, что кутэ -- это qt. Языкам не обучен. А насчёт полного решения для автора вопроса -- увы. Но вот половину (серверная часть без передачи имени и пр. -- только данные) вроде написал. [@RocketDeath](/users/2154/rocketdeath): в реальной программе возвращаемые значения надо проверять, просто мне с ними писать длиннее.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#ifdef __WIN32__
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
const int qlen = 1; // длина очереди соединений
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in sin, ssin;
    int ssock, sock, len;
    unsigned char buf[1000];
#ifdef __WIN32__
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 0);
    WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    _setmode(_fileno( stdin ), _O_BINARY );
#endif
        sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        memset((char *)&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
        sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        sin.sin_port = htons((u_short)atoi(argv[1]));
        bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
        listen(sock, qlen);
        ssock = accept(sock, NULL, &len);
        while(len = fread(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            send(ssock, buf, len, 0);
        }
#ifdef __WIN32__
        closesocket(ssock);
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
#else
        close(ssock);
        close(sock);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Единственный параметр -- номер порта. Файл с stdin (можно использовать перенаправление)

Comment: while(len = fread(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), sizeof buf, stdin))
это же вечный цикл, сдесь где-то ошибка...

Comment: Из `man fread` `If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).`. Когда читать нечего (EOF), вернёт и 0. И капут циклу.

Comment: Пробовал сделать таким образом
 while(!feof(in)) {
 fread(bufer,1,sizeof(bufer),in);
 send(current,bufer,sizeof(bufer),0);
 } 
но fread читает все байты, а не количество, равное емкости буфера.

Comment: Это как? Подробнее можно? Причём, использовать результат fread необходимо, если у вас длина файла не кратна размеру bufer.

Comment: Нашел в чем подвох.
FILE *in = fopen("SocketServer.exe","rb");
Если вместо "rb", вставить "r", то fread читает лиш один раз и выходит из цикла while(!feof(in)).

Comment: Страшное дело. Значит в SocketServer.exe байт с кодом 0x1a встречается в первом куске. Только вот это вряд ли то, что вам надо.
Нарисуйте `int s = 0; while(len = fread(bufer, 1, sizeof bufer, in) s+=len; printf("%d", s);` и посмотрите, что получится с режимами "r" и "rb".

Comment: Не знаю что я должен был заметить, но заметил такую разницу между простым и бинарным чтением: 
-в простом чтении позиция в потоке не соответствует количеству прочитанных байт, при чтении буфер не заполняется полностью, а также примерно на 161 кругу цикла ловится тот самый 0x1a(конец файла) и выходит из цикла.
- в бинарном чтении же буфер заполняется полностью, то есть количество прочитанных байт за один цикл одинаковое и ровняется размеру буфера. Позиция в потоке ровняется количеству прочитанных байт.

Comment: Всё нормально. В текстовом файле dos (выше уже отмечалось) последовательность `\r\n` (или наоборот?) заменяется при чтении на `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

*alexiz, что есть WSAStartup? =)
Под виндой с сокетами работал только из кутэ. Но знаю что в лине и винде разные API для этого взаимодействия.*

Rocketdeath, разбейте задачу на подзадачи и все у вас получится.

1. Передайте на сервер какую-нибудь захардкоженную строку ("Hello" к
       примеру)
2. Считайте простой текстовый файл в память (и выведите содержимое на консоль, к примеру).
3. 1+2, считали файл, отправили

Comment: Я не знаю, кто такая кутэ (какая-то грузинская фамилия), а WSAStartup -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx -- "nitiates use of the Winsock DLL by a process." Должна в виндах вызываться первой из winsock-вызовов. А насчёт разных -- так есть некоторое, вполне приемлемое общее подмножество. (т.е. будет работать и в winsock, и в bsd-sockets.

Comment: кутэ это Qt, который фрэймворк, если вы меня конечно не тролите на тему неправильной записи =)

ну а ссылку я видел, я знаю что такое гугл =)

Answer (score 1):

Вы работаете в винде и проблемы с двоичным файлом.

Открывайте на чтение:

```
FILE *in = fopen(filename,"rb");
```

читайте в цикле до EOF поблочно fread() в буфер, который будете пердавать по сокету.
Прочли - передали (send()) и т.д. Будут читаться все симвлы (^Z тоже), никаких доплнительных \r на будет. Аналогично для записи в файл fopen(...,"wb").

Имеет смысл сделать свой простой протокол передачи файла, например:

```
Cli -> имя файла -> Serv
Serv -> OK size-in-bytes block-size
   или  No such file
Serv -> блок 1
Cli <- читает блок 1 (recv()) пишет его в выходной файл (fwrite())
...
Serv -> блок n
```

Прочли все байты - ОК.

Размер файла (и его атрибуты) можно узнать вызывая функцию stat()

```
#include <sys/stat> по другому символ < ввести не получается
```

Что-то в таком духе. Будут *конкретные* вопросы - задавайте.

Comment: Судя по всему автор ждет полного решения =\

Comment: почемуже) я решаю и мирно наблюдаю ответы, черпая из них нужное для меня)