# Проблемы с отправкой jpeg C++ socket

Tags: jpeg, сокет, c++

Добрый день,использовал код по вашему адресу

[Передача файла по сети через сокеты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/67445/c-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B)
"Передача файла по сети через сокеты" :

```
FILE *in = fopen("SocketServer.exe","rb");
while(!feof(in)) {
b=fread(bufer,1,sizeof(bufer),in);
size=ftell(in);
printf("bytes read: %d, part:%d, pos: %ld \n",b,i,size);
if(b!=0)
send(current,bufer,b,0);
i++;
}
```

но у меня при передаче каким то образом искажается jpeg, становится зеленым, сдвигаются пиксели...вероятно теряется несущая информация, как в статье по ссылке, там грешат на strlen, возможно ли такое здесь? Прошу помочь разобраться.

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/606052-socket-send-binary-jpeg

"...strlen determines the length of the string by the position of the first NULL
characiter it finds \0 or ascii 0. Binary data, including jpegs, can have
NULL bytes as valid data. You will need some other way to determine how
much data to send (look at the return value of file.read for example)..."

Answer (score 1):

Я бы тут погрешил на feof(in). Лучше подсчитать длину файла с помощью

FILE* f= fopen(...);
if(f) {
fseek(f,SEEK_END,0);
long size = ftell(f); 
fseek(f,SEEK_SET,0);
....
итд
....
}

и передавать порции байтов пока не будет достигнута конечная длина.

Comment: IMHO нет. И feof(in) и такая, например, запись

    while((b = fread(bufer,1,sizeof(bufer),in)) > 0)
      if (send(current,bufer,b,0) != b)
        fatal ("send file");

работают правильно. Надо искать ошибку в других частях кода.